# Why aren't markdown images showing in PyCharm notebooks?

Tags: image, jupyter-notebook, pycharm, markdown

There seems to be quite a fuss about this issue with very little in the way of answers out there. Similar questions have even been asked here multiple times without any valid answers.

I'll show you what I'm seeing, ans what I suspect many others are seeing:

[broken image: PyCharm ipynb md](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CnaD.png)

I've properly headed the markdown cell, and the md for image inclusion is correctly formatted. The path is correct. There aren't any typos anywhere. Yet, I have consistently seen this particular issue rear its head over and over again. If I opened this in Jupyter Notebook, the image would be perfectly included. In fact, I used this exact tag in the README.md file right next to the notebook file, "types_and_metaclasses.ipynb"; and PyCharm resolves it perfectly without a hitch.

Does anybody know why this happens to be the case in PyCharm's ipynb md implementation?
Is there a setting we're all missing or some syntax specific to PyCharm's notebook rendering (if there is, I couldn't find it in the JetBrains documentation)?

I've read this issue across multiple boards and posts, yet I haven't found one valid explanation or fix (including here).

This is a really frustrating bug (if it *is* a bug); and getting this to work would be awesome :)

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try `![Attribute Lookup](python_confs_notes/media/attribute_lookup.png)`?

Comment: @Ahx Thank you, I just tried it. Unfortunately it's still not working.  :(